При импорте telebot через командную строку, VS Code не видит библиотеку telebot
Я делаю свой 1-й телеграм-бот, я импортировал библиотеку «pip install pyTelegramBotApi» через командную строку, написало, что всё успешно, высветилась такая менюшка. (У меня подозрения на жёлтые буквы «warning»)
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Lsy4KrvOfPHKuQ

Но когда я зашёл в VS Code и написал тестовый код, под буквами «telebot», появилась волнистая линия (ошибка),
(видно на скриншоте).
https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Y4wICGHP3kyOVQ

Откройте командную строку в вашем проекте VS Code и установите библиотеку через неё, до этого вы установили библиотеку просто в интерпретатор на диске C:

Если вы работаете в виртуальном окружении, то нажмите Быстрое исправление - Выберите другой интерпретатор - выбираете путь до venv

(ИСПРАВЛЕНО) У меня в самом «Телеграмме» был выключен бот, надо просто было нажать «Перезагрузить бота»
